# How to calculate sin(65) without a calculator.

Tags: trigonometry

I know about the sum and difference formula but I can't think of two values which will be able to use for sin(65). Therefore, I come to the question: How to calculate sin(65) without a calculator.

Comment: Is that $\sin(65^\circ)$ or $\sin(65\operatorname{rad})$?

Comment: I assume it is degrees, my teacher just said sin(65). So i'm not even sure actually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they meant degrees.

Comment: Use a slide rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$65^\circ$ isn't a nice one, unfortunately: the only constructible angles with natural degree measure are multiples of $3^\circ$.

This is a little complicated to prove directly - a problem since antiquity, the last piece of the puzzle didn't appear until 1837, when [Wantzel proved that $20^\circ$ was unconstructible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection).  Suffice it to say for now that you can get angles of the form $\frac{a}{2^b\cdot3\cdot5\cdot17\cdot257\cdot 65537}$ circles, and $65^\circ$ needs another $3$ on the bottom to get there, being $\frac{13}{72}$ of a circle.

The upshot for you is that you won't be able to "not use a calculator" to find this one.

Answer (score 3):

$$65 = 45 + 20$$

So if you can figure out sine and cosine of 20, you're in good shape. Fortunately,  there are triple-angle formulas:

$$
\sin(3x) = 3\sin x-4\sin^3 x \\
\cos(3x) = \cos^3 x-3\cos x \sin^2 x = \cos^3 x-3\cos x (1 - \cos^2 x)
$$
Since you know $\sin(60) = \sqrt{3}/2$, you know that the sine of 20 -- call it $u$ -- satisfies the equation

$$
\sqrt{3}/2 = 3u-4u^3
$$
From this, you can solve for $u$ (using Cardano's formula for the solution of a cubic). To be honest, this is a complete pain in the neck, but at least it's a route to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Then [from this link](http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf), with the [methodology explained here](http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/how-do-you-find-exact-values-for-the-sine-of-all-angles-6212):

$$ \sin 65^\circ = -\left(-\frac12 + \frac i2 \sqrt{3}\right) \left( -\frac{1}{32} \sqrt{6} \left(1- \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right) + \frac{i}{32} \sqrt{-6 \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \right)^2 + 16 }\right)^{1/3} -\left(-\frac12 - \frac i2 \sqrt{3}\right) \left( -\frac{1}{32} \sqrt{6} \left(1- \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right) + \frac{i}{32} \sqrt{-6 \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \right)^2 + 16 }\right)^{1/3} $$

(Note that $65^\circ$ is not constructible, so we should not expect any expression involving a finite amount of additions, multiplications and square roots.)

Answer (score -1):

Split it up, into sin 45 plus sin 30. You will get sin 75, then subtract sin 10(you can do by using sin(3x) formula). Then you will get sin 65

Comment: Since the problem asks us "to calculate $\sin 65$ without a calculator", you should give more details of the actual calculation for Readers to follow.  In particular the suggestion of getting $\sin 10$ by using a triple angle formula seems difficult by manual or mental calculation.